# Noob on Rails -- needing assistance improving method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the "select" helper to iterate through a nested array to display the options attribute on my form.

Here's currently what I have:

```
  def smtp_delays
    [['5 seconds', 5], ['10 seconds', 10], ['15 seconds', 15], ['30 seconds', 30], ['60 seconds', 60]]
  end
```

And here's how my form is going through it:

```
<%= ff.select(:smtp_delay, @test.settings.smtp_delays, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
```

The output of this on my page turns out to this:

```
<option value="5">5 seconds</option>
<option value="10">10 seconds</option>
<option value="15">15 seconds</option>
<option value="30">30 seconds</option>
<option value="60">60 seconds</option>
```

Is there a more efficient way to handle this process? Like, if I wanted to add another entry, I'm sure there's a much more efficient way than adding another `["45 seconds", 45]`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might shorten things up for you a bit

```
[5, 10, 15, 30, 45].map { |s| ["%d seconds" % s, s] }
```

Output

```
#=> [["5 seconds", 5], ["10 seconds", 10], ["15 seconds", 15], ["30 seconds", 30], ["45 seconds", 45]]
```

---

In the `ActionView` context, you also have [pluralize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize) available

So you could do something like this

```
 <%= ff.select :smtp_delay @test.settings.smtp_delays.map { |s| [pluralize(s, "second"), s] } %>
```

I probably wouldn't put that right in the view though. Might be more appropriate to use Presenter Pattern to keep the views clean from this kind of thing